# how can I tell jquery not to return true in a function if the a href has a specific class?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using "ajax for all" Wordpress plugin to asynchronously load content, but I cannot use any Lightbox plugin as after clicking the image the page reloads; I would like to override the function if the `a href` has a specific class

```
$('a').live( 'click',
        function() {
            if ( $(this).attr('target') )  {
                return true;
            }
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            $.bbq.pushState({ url: href });
            if ( href.indexOf('#') == 0 ) {
                return true;
            }
            dispatcher.fire(href);
            return false;
        }
    );
```

How should I modify this function to make it return false if the "a" is an image with a specific class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method to check if an element has a particular class.

Try this:

```
 $('a').live( 'click',      function() {
               //Check if the element has a class and if yes, return false.
        if($(this).hasClass("<YOUR_CLASS_NAME>")){
            return false;
        }
        else if ( $(this).attr('target') )  {
            return true;
        }
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $.bbq.pushState({ url: href });
        if ( href.indexOf('#') == 0 ) {
            return true;
        }
        dispatcher.fire(href);
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').live( 'click', function( e ) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  if ( $(this).attr('target') ) { return true; } var href = $(this).attr('href'); $.bbq.pushState({ url: href }); if ( href.indexOf('#') == 0 ) { return true; } dispatcher.fire(href); return false; } );
```

This way you prevent the default link behavior. If you still need to do this only for a specified class link, just add a if statement

```
if ($(this).hasClass('myclass') {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Note you could also use `return false;` instead of `e.preventDefault()`.